# How to interate a json string and save it to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have data sent from a php page and I want to save the 'date' and 'count' values into two different arrays in javascript. But I don't know how to access the data below. Any help?

```
{
  "0": {
    "date": "12/24/21",
    "count": 1
  },
  "1": {
    "date": "01/01/22",
    "count": 1
  },
  "3": {
    "date": "01/02/22",
    "count": 2
  },
  "6": {
    "date": "01/04/22",
    "count": 3
  },
  "7": {
    "date": "01/05/22",
    "count": 1
  },
  "9": {
    "date": "01/06/22",
    "count": 2
  }
}
```

javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/page",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) { 
        let date = [];
        let count = [];
        // code to save the values from php page

  },
   error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: read about `.forEach` loop and use `.push` to add data to your empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing some parenthesis and curly brackets in there after the success field. You might wanna fix it up a lil like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/page",
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
      let date = [];
      let count = [];
      // code to save the values from php page
      for (keys in data) {
        //do ya thang 
      }
    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
});
```

With it all nice and spruced up, you could utilize a few methods for iterating through that JSON object that's returned. You could either get the objects keys and use them to iterate through the object with *Object.keys(yourObject)*, or you could use a *for-in loop* like above to iterate through the object.

Either way, you can iterate through the object and push the date and count vals for each field in the object onto your date and count arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data =
  '{ "0": { "date": "12/24/21", "count": 1 }, "1": { "date": "01/01/22", "count": 1 }, "3": { "date": "01/02/22", "count": 2 }, "6": { "date": "01/04/22", "count": 3 }, "7": { "date": "01/05/22", "count": 1 }, "9": { "date": "01/06/22", "count": 2 } }';
const obj = JSON.parse(data);

const dateArr = [];
const countArr = [];

for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
  const { date, count } = value;
  dateArr.push(date);
  countArr.push(count);
}
console.log("dateArr", dateArr);
console.log("countArr", countArr);
```

this is quite straightforward, if your data is `json`, you need to parse it to Javascript first using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and then use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and a loop to push your data to your variables.

Here I'm using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop